# Sampling of rectangle apertures

Tags: analysis, functions

for analyzing of near field and far field diffraction a rectangular aperture shall be used. For modelling purposes the rectangular aperture shall be described with "infenitesimal" tiny openings/points.

[image: Example sampling of rectangular aperture]

This rectangular aperture has the following math. description:

$$U(x_0,y_0) = \text{rect}\Biggl(\frac{x_0}{w_x},\frac{y_0}{w_y}\Biggr)$$

I found a lot of stuff about the sampling of the rect-functions (one dimension), sampling theorem, Fourier transform, etc. But I cannot link that to my problem.

So, how can I determine how many openings are at least necessary in order to represent a reactangle aperture?

Comment: I think you need to explain better what you want help with or this is likely to be closed as off topic or lack of context.

Comment: I just want to know how a two-dimensional aperture can be sampled. The resulting sampling points should be able to represent a "real" rectangle aperture, which is dercibed by a continuous function.

Comment: Maybe the answer is "the more, the better." How will the distance between grid points affect the accuracy of your answers? I don't know how anyone can guess that from the amount and type of information you've given. The formula for $U(x_0,y_0)$ has no relationship whatsoever to the distance between points as far as I can tell, unless $w_x$ and $w_y$ count numbers of points, in which case it still tells us nothing about how big those numbers _should_ be.

Comment: Ok. Let me explain following idea. Let's assume we want to sample a common rect function. According to the sampling theorem the sampling frequency must be twice as the cut-off frequency. So, if the rectangle function is correctly sampled it can be reconstructed again. An under- and oversampling shall be avoided.

Comment: Thus, I thought that this approach could also be applied to the rectangular aperture. Meaning that this rectangular shape should be replaced by tiny point sources. I need this approximation in order reduce the calc time for the near and far field diffraction. Maybe I'm only on the wrong way... and there is an other solution....